# How to support quotes in a function that highlights keywords

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, match, preg-match-all

I have this function which highlights keywords.  It works great but it doesn't seem to work with single and double quotes.

```
function highlight($input, $keywords) {

    // Hello Mr Regex
    preg_match_all('~\w+~', $keywords, $match);

    // If there's no match
    if(!$match) { return $input; }

    // Case sensitive search
    //$result = '~\\b(' . implode('|', $match[0]) . ')\\b~';

    // Case insenstive search
    $result = '~\\b(' . implode('|', $match[0]) . ')\\b~i';

    // Return highlighted text
    return preg_replace($result, '<strong>$0</strong>', $input);

}
```

`$keywords = "just another what's little's test";`

`$input = "here what what's just looking little's another's this's for another one that requires a test";`

---

Result: *here **what what's just** looking **little's another's** this**'s** for **another** one that requires a **test***

---

In this example, it shouldn't be highlighting the ***'s*** on ***this's***

---

I've also tried using `htmlspecialchars()` for both the input and keywords but this also doesn't seem to get matched.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\w` is only letters, digits, and underscores.  If you want to include quotes or apostrophes you can create a character class:

```
preg_match_all('~[\w\'"]+~' ...
```

Comment: Can you recommend any good sources for learning regular expressions?

Comment: If you want to _really_ learn regex, read: [Mastering Regular Expressions (3rd Edition)](http://www.amazon.com/Mastering-Regular-Expressions-Jeffrey-Friedl/dp/0596528124 "By Jeffrey Friedl. Best book on Regex - ever!")